# Issue with ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an problem with how JPA/Hibernate/Spring Boot behave when ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException is received.

The relevant code:

The entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ApplyFlowToConnector {
:::
    @Version
    private int dbVersion;
:::
}
```

The repo:

```
public interface ApplyFlowToConnectorRepo extends JpaRepository<ApplyFlowToConnector, Long> {
```

Invoking code:

```
    public ApplyFlowToConnector updateTimeApplyFlowRequested(ApplyFlowToConnector applyFlowToConnector, ZonedDateTime time) {
        return retryOnce(applyFlowToConnector, (a) -> a.setTimeApplyFlowRequested(time));
    }
```

The problematic code:

```
    public ApplyFlowToConnector retryOnce(ApplyFlowToConnector applyFlowToConnector, Consumer<ApplyFlowToConnector> applyFlowToConnectorModifier) {
        try {
            applyFlowToConnectorModifier.accept(applyFlowToConnector);
            ApplyFlowToConnector ret = applyFlowToConnectorRepo.saveAndFlush(applyFlowToConnector);
            return ret;
        } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
            Optional<ApplyFlowToConnector> applyFlowToConnectorOptional = applyFlowToConnectorRepo.findById(applyFlowToConnector.getId());
            if(applyFlowToConnectorOptional.isPresent()) {
                ApplyFlowToConnector newApplyFlowToConnector = applyFlowToConnectorOptional.get();
                applyFlowToConnectorModifier.accept(newApplyFlowToConnector);
                ApplyFlowToConnector ret = applyFlowToConnectorRepo.saveAndFlush(newApplyFlowToConnector);
                return ret;
            }
            return applyFlowToConnector;
        }
    }
```

We want retryOnce() to handle 2 simultaneous identical API requests.

We send 2 simultaneous API requests to the server each of which retrieves the same applyFlowToConnector object with the same dbVersion (say 209). Each then makes a call to a remote server to retrieve some information and just before returning the response to the caller, each invokes updateTimeApplyFlowRequested() with the same applyFlowToConnector. The first call to retryOnce() results in success, returning an applyFlowToConnector object with dbVersion of 210. The second call to retryOnce() fails as expected, throwing ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException. We then retrieve the applyFlowToConnector object again and get the newApplyFlowToConnector, it has a dbVersion of 210. We then apply the modifier to update the timeApplyFlowRequested. So far everything is as expected.

But the next call to applyFlowToConnectorRepo.saveAndFlush(newApplyFlowToConnector) fails, throwing another ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException. The sql generated from saveAndFlush() indicates that the update statement to the DB is being made with dbVersion of 209, which is not the right version, causing the exception. I'm at a loss to figure out how to further debug this issue.

We are using a webflux spring boot application. The DB is postgresql (blocking). None of the calling functions are marked with @Transactional.

I hope somebody has some insight into how I can further debug this issue or solve it.